# How to Roll Up and Roll Down Delphi form with "bsSingle" style?

Tags: delphi

How to roll up and roll down Delphi Form when `Double Click` happened if `Form.Style:=bsSingle`?

I have defined the following codes :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    OldClientHeight: Integer;
    procedure WMNCLButtonDblClk(var msg: TWMNCLButtonDblClk); message WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.WMNCLButtonDblClk(var msg: TWMNCLButtonDblClk);
var
  Height : integer;
begin
  if (Msg.HitTest = HTCAPTION) then
  Caption := 'Double Click';
   begin
     if (ClientHeight = 0) then
       begin
         for Height := 0 to OldClientHeight do ClientHeight := Height;
         Application.ProcessMessages;
       end
     else
       begin
         OldClientHeight := ClientHeight;
         for Height := OldClientHeight downto 0 do ClientHeight := Height;
         Application.ProcessMessages;
       end;
   end;
end;

end.
```

if the `Form.Style:=bsSizeable` the code works perfectly.

But my `Form.Style:=bsSingle` and I have implement for it.

So I have tried my own trick and coded in other way as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.WMNCLButtonDblClk(var msg: TWMNCLButtonDblClk);
var
  Height : integer;
begin
  if (Msg.HitTest = HTCAPTION) then
  Caption := 'Double Click';
  Form1.BorderStyle := bsSizeable;
   begin
     if (ClientHeight = 0) then
       begin
         for Height := 0 to OldClientHeight do ClientHeight := Height;
         Application.ProcessMessages;
       end
     else
       begin
         OldClientHeight := ClientHeight;
         for Height := OldClientHeight downto 0 do ClientHeight := Height;
         Application.ProcessMessages;
       end;
   end;
  Form1.BorderStyle := bsSingle;
end;
```

but i am facing the following problem :

1. At the time of `Rolling Down` [image: Rolling Down] if `DoubleBuffered:=true`, the `Form.Background` becomes `Blue` (My Windows XP theme is default blue) then changes to `clBtnFace` (My `Form.Background:=clBtnFace`). And some flicker is there.
2. At the time of `Rolling Up` [image: Rolling Up] it is not completely rolled up, some form background is visible, if I use my trick.

**Please any one give me the solution so that the Form may be rolled up and down completely with 'bsSingle' Form Style.**

Comment: Any Idea to implement using Timer?

Comment: Your `begin` statement (for `if (Msg.HitTest`) is wrong in both statements. The `begin` should be immediately following that line, not following the change of the `Caption` or setting style. Both should be `if (Msg.HitTest = HTCAPTION) then begin`. (Don't know if that has anything to do with your issue, but the flow of execution is wrong.)

Comment: Please show the right flow of execution.

Comment: I just told you how to fix it. Move the first `begin` after the `if` statement` up until it's right after the `if` statement itself, exactly like I wrote. If you set a breakpoint in the debugger, set the form style to `bsSizeable`, and step through the code, you'll see what it does and why it's wrong. I can't write more in a comment; there's no space.

Comment: Call `Repaint` after each adjustment of the height for the background problem. And you don't need to set the borderstyle temporarily to bsSizeable, just adjust your condition to enter the loop, `if ClientHeight = 0`, the thing is ClientHeight is never 0 when you have a single border. Can't tell why at the moment..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `Repaint` in each iteration of setting the height of the form to get rid of the background problem.

```
 ..
 for Height := OldClientHeight downto 0 do 
 begin
   ClientHeight := Height;
   Repaint;
 end;
 ..
```

You don't have to switch the borderstyle for your animation to work. The reason that your code fails is that the `ClientHeight` of a fixed border window is never 0 by default.

In any case, calling `Application.ProcessMessages`, you depend on the processing capability of the machine that the program is running on for animation speed. Using a `TTimer` would avoid that. An example could be like this:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  private
    FOldClientHeight: Integer;
    FContracted: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure WMNCLButtonDblClk(var Msg: TWMNCLButtonDblClk);
      message WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoubleBuffered := True;
  FOldClientHeight := ClientHeight;
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  Timer1.Interval := 10;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMNCLButtonDblClk(var Msg: TWMNCLButtonDblClk);
begin
  if Msg.HitTest = HTCAPTION then
    Timer1.Enabled := True
  else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  MinClientHeight: Integer;
begin
  MinClientHeight := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMIN) -
      GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION) - 2 * GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFIXEDFRAME);

  if FContracted then begin
    if ClientHeight < FOldClientHeight then
      ClientHeight := ClientHeight + 5
    else begin
      FContracted := False;
      Timer1.Enabled := False;
    end;
  end else begin
    if ClientHeight > MinClientHeight then
      ClientHeight := ClientHeight - 5
    else begin
      FContracted := True;
      Timer1.Enabled := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Regarding "rolling up *completely*", the system seems to take the "minimum height of a window" seriously. Functions like `SetWindowPos`, `SetWindowPlacement` or responding to f.i. `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` does not help with that. Setting a region on the window, which could be an alternative, ruins the visual styles with DWM, which renders it unusable. However, responding to `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` seems to help. Please note that there's no guarantee that it will work on a specific version of OS. I only tested it with XP and W7, if you want to use it anyway, see below:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  private
    FOldClientHeight: Integer;
    FContracted, FForceCompletelyContracted: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure WMNCLButtonDblClk(var Msg: TWMNCLButtonDblClk);
      message WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK;
    procedure WMWindowPosChanging(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanging);
      message WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BorderStyle := bsSingle;
  DoubleBuffered := True;
  FOldClientHeight := ClientHeight;
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  Timer1.Interval := 10;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMNCLButtonDblClk(var Msg: TWMNCLButtonDblClk);
begin
  if Msg.HitTest = HTCAPTION then
    Timer1.Enabled := True
  else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMWindowPosChanging(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanging);
begin
  inherited;
  if FContracted and ((Message.WindowPos.flags and SWP_NOSIZE) = 0) and
      FForceCompletelyContracted then
    Message.WindowPos.cy := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION) +
         GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFIXEDFRAME);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  MinClientHeight: Integer;
begin
  if FContracted then begin
    if FForceCompletelyContracted then begin
      FForceCompletelyContracted := False;
      SetWindowPos(Handle, 0, 0, 0, Width, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOZORDER);
      Exit;
    end;
    if ClientHeight < FOldClientHeight then
      ClientHeight := ClientHeight + 5
    else begin
      FContracted := False;
      Timer1.Enabled := False;
    end;
  end else begin
    MinClientHeight := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMIN) -
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION) - 2 * GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFIXEDFRAME);
    if ClientHeight > MinClientHeight then
      ClientHeight := ClientHeight - 5
    else begin
      FContracted := True;
      Timer1.Enabled := False;
      FForceCompletelyContracted := True;
      SetWindowPos(Handle, 0, 0, 0, Width, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOZORDER);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Wow! Your code works great. But the only thing is that you have forgotten to remember that some `Form Area` is still there for the first code as my `Second Picture` i.e. `Rolling Up Picture`. Thanks. Thanks a lot.